# PHP malformed utf-8 when decoding json string posted using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, hex, json

I am working on a project where I cannot modify the PHP code. I can only modify the JavaScript since I am writing it.

I post hex encoded data containing UTF-8 characters to a PHP script. When the PHP script tries to decoded the data as JSON. The decode function returns null and get the following error "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded".

The Hex decoding seems to modify the encoding, for example the french sentence

> L‘équitation en France est le troisième sport en nombre de licenciés

*will be converted into:*

> L\x18équitation en France est le troisième sport en nombre de licenciés

It gets worse for the Arabic sentence, or any language that uses non Latin characters, as it is not readable anymore.

Is there any thing that I can do on the Javascript part to solve the issue. Maybe a conversion of some sort to preserve the sentences before converting them to HEX?

He is a code simple the demo the issue:

**PHP Code:**

```
if(!empty($_POST)){

    print_r($_POST);

    $data = Hex2String($_POST["data"]);

    $result = json_decode($data, true);
    $errors = json_last_error();
    echo "Errpr: {$errors}<br />";

    var_dump($result);
    exit();
}

function Hex2String($hex){
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2){
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}
```

**JavaScript code**

```
    /***
     * Converts a string into a hex representation of the string.
     * @param {string} string
     * @returns {String}
     */
    function Str2Hex (tmp){
        var str = "";
        for (var i=0; i<tmp.length; i++)
            str += ("00" + (tmp.charCodeAt(i)).toString(16)).substr(-2);
        return (str);
    }

    $(function(){


        var data = {
            frenchText: "L‘équitation en France est le troisième sport en nombre de licenciés",
            germanText: "Das für sein karolingisches in Höxter",
            arabicText: "جانب من آثار مدينة جدارا اليونانيَّة"
        };


        $.post("index.php?DBGSESSID=1", {data:Str2Hex(JSON.stringify(data))},function(data) {

            console.log($("#result"));
            console.log(data);

            $("#result").html(data);
        });
    });
```

**Full example:**

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_POST)){

        print_r($_POST);

        $data = Hex2String($_POST["data"]);

        $result = json_decode($data, true);
        $errors = json_last_error();
        echo "Errpr: {$errors}<br />";

        var_dump($result);
        exit();
    }

    function Hex2String($hex){
        $string='';
        for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2){
            $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
        }
        return $string;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="result">

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">


            /***
             * Converts a string into a hex representation of the string.
             * @param {string} string
             * @returns {String}
             */
            function Str2Hex (tmp){
                var str = "";
                for (var i=0; i<tmp.length; i++)
                    str += ("00" + (tmp.charCodeAt(i)).toString(16)).substr(-2);
                return (str);
            }

            $(function(){


                var data = {
                    frenchText: "L‘équitation en France est le troisième sport en nombre de licenciés",
                    germanText: "Das für sein karolingisches in Höxter",
                    arabicText: "جانب من آثار مدينة جدارا اليونانيَّة"
                };


                $.post("index.php?DBGSESSID=1", {data:Str2Hex(JSON.stringify(data))},function(data) {

                    console.log($("#result"));
                    console.log(data);

                    $("#result").html(data);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't you remove the hex-coding? Json fully supports utf8, so no need for another encoding. The `Hex2String` should not modify the string if it does not contain hex codes.

Comment: Sadly I cannot. The data gets converted into Hex because it will get encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for it:

```
function forceUnicodeEncoding(string) {
    return unescape(encodeURIComponent(string));
}

data.frenchText = forceUnicodeEncoding(data.frenchText);
data.germanText = forceUnicodeEncoding(data.germanText);
data.arabicText = forceUnicodeEncoding(data.arabicText);
```

***The only issue is that the unescape function has been deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5.***

Source:
http://andre.arko.net/2012/09/18/force-encoding-in-javascript/